# Can't get PostGIS to work with Heroku / Rails - NoMethodError: undefined method `geography' / 'st_point'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, postgis

I get these errors when trying to either migrate or db:schema:load on Heroku with Rails 5.0.1

Gemfile

```
# PostGIS adapter
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  postgis_extension: postgis
  schema_search_path: public, postgis
production:
  <<: *default
  database: appname_production
  username: appname
  password: <%= ENV['APPNAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Migration

```
t.st_point :location, geographic: true, null: false
```

schema.rb

```
t.geography "location", limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"point", :geographic=>true}, null: false
```

Buildpacks

```
$ heroku buildpacks
=== appname-staging Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git
2. heroku/ruby
```

Running either `heroku run rake db:migrate` or `heroku run rake db:schema:load` gives `` NoMethodError: undefined method `st_point' ``, `` NoMethodError: undefined method `geography' ``, respectively. How can I fix this? What am I missing?

Comment: @How did you end up fixing this?

Comment: did you mange to fix that issue ?

Answer (score 4):

In case of that this will help someone i manged to solve the issue by using

```
  production:
    <<: *default
    url: <%= ENV.fetch('DATABASE_URL', '').sub(/^postgres/, "postgis") %>
    database: databasename_production
    username: databasename
    password: <%= ENV['databasename_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

in my database.yml file

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the database url

https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter/issues/174